# What is more useful when optimising for Eclipse PDT or PyDev - launcher.XXMaxPermSize or Xms,Xmx?

Tags: eclipse-pdt

I use Eclipse with PDT. Most optimization solutions mention increasing the `Xms` and `Xmx` values to enable Eclipse to handle more Java objects. I am curious about `XXMaxPermSize`. Increasing its value increased the memory the java process used.

For a non-Java IDE usage, which of these three (or all three) should be increased? My eclipse.ini file contents are as below:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Update: The following is the updated eclipse.ini I am using.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

For PDT or other non-Java development the size of these variables should be largely irrelevant as long as Eclipse itself is running fine (maybe regardless of that).

From the [ini documentation page](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html):

> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize  (Executable) If specified, and the executable detects that the VM being used is a Sun VM, then the
>   launcher will automatically add the -XX:MaxPermSize= vm
>   argument.  The executable is not capable of detecting Sun VMs on all
>   platforms.

This [blog post](http://blog.xam.dk/?p=58) is also helpful, specifically mentioning the Xms Xmx are separate from PermGen space, the syntax requirement that args must be on separate lines (as you have above), and:

> The best way to know if your command line arguments actually has been
>   passed in correctly is to go to Help/About [Product Name] and click
>   “Configuration Details” and check that the property “eclipse.vmargs”
>   contain the values you expected.

Finally, [this page](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html#ixzz2MKDWewYE) mentions which errors might be seen if the settings are too low:

```
1) Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (The Xmx variable)
2) Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space (The XXMaxPermSize variable)
```